# Can Magento Configurable Swatches be disabled if not used?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, configurable-product, swatches

I don't use Magento Configurable Swatches. Disabling via Mage_ConfigurableSwatches.xml, will this have any side effect? I am looking for performance improvement which I see if disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable Mage_ConfigurableSwatches without further ado.

This module has been added on top in Magento 1.9.1 and no other core modules depend on it. It is integrated in the default RWD theme, but only using its own layout XML and own templates.

To disable core modules without changing core files I would recommend adding a new file, for example `Zzz_Deactivate.xml` with the following content:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_ConfigurableSwatches>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_ConfigurableSwatches>
    </modules>
</config>
```

The XML files in `app/etc/modules` are loaded alphabetically, so a name like that will ensure that it's loaded last.